# AnyTransition issue with simple view update in macOS

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have 2 user view called user1 and user2, I am updating user with button, and I want give a transition animation to update, but for some reason my transition does not work, as I wanted, the issue is there that Text animated correctly but image does not, it stay in its place and it does not move with Text to give a smooth transition animation.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var show: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            if (show) {
                
                UserView(label: { Text("User 1") })
                    .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: AnyTransition.move(edge: Edge.trailing), removal: AnyTransition.move(edge: Edge.leading)))
            }
            else {
                
                UserView(label: { Text("User 2") })
                    .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: AnyTransition.move(edge: Edge.leading), removal: AnyTransition.move(edge: Edge.trailing)))
                
            }
            
            Button("update") { show.toggle() }
            
        }
        .padding()
        .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 1.0), value: show)
        
    }
}


struct UserView<Label: View>: View {
    
    let label: () -> Label
    @State private var heightOfLabel: CGFloat? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            
            if let unwrappedHeight: CGFloat = heightOfLabel {
                
                Image(systemName: "person")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: unwrappedHeight, height: unwrappedHeight)
                
            }
            
            label()
                .background(GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Color.clear
                        .onAppear(perform: { heightOfLabel = proxy.size.height })

                })
            
            
            Spacer(minLength: CGFloat.zero)
            
        }
        .animation(nil, value: heightOfLabel)
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `heightOfLabel` doesn't have to be optional, and then it works:

```
struct UserView<Label: View>: View {
    
    let label: () -> Label
    @State private var heightOfLabel: CGFloat = .zero // not optional
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "person")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: heightOfLabel, height: heightOfLabel)
            label()
                .background(GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Color.clear
                        .onAppear(perform: { heightOfLabel = proxy.size.height })
                })
            Spacer(minLength: CGFloat.zero)
        }
        .animation(nil, value: heightOfLabel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves the issue, do you know why optional make issue there? I see no understandable issue to having optional.

Comment: if your `heightOfLabel`is optional, it is nil at start when the view is initiated, and your image is not drawn at all. then it gets set, and your image is animated into the view. And these interfere with you button action that should start the animation.